# Did Jovanka Houska defend women's British chess championship?

Tags: women, british

[Harriet Hunt](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/37102/both-at-least-wgm-and-phd-doctorate) is the new women's British chess champion after [Jovanka Houska](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/37102/both-at-least-wgm-and-phd-doctorate) won it the last 4 times in a row for a total of 9 times. Harriet is now a 5-time champion but last won the title in 1999 (22 years ago).

Surely Jovanka could've beaten Harriet, who appeared to have been focused more on studies for the last 22 years and didn't seem to have been playing in the British chess championships from 2016 to 2019. But it seems Jovanka actually wasn't around to defend the title in 2021. Is that so? If so, then why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thought I'd share [this](https://twitter.com/thelittlehat/status/1468815780716371968) via [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) after that [answer was accepted](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35171/why-is-jovanka-houska-introduced-as-a-wgm-when-she-holds-the-more-prestigious-im): Jovanka chose to stay in Norway (after [Meltwater Champions Chess Tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champions_Chess_Tour_2021) I guess) and prepare for the [FIDE Women's Grand Swiss Tournament 2021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDE_Women%27s_Grand_Swiss_Tournament_2021).

[image]

Comment: ref *(after Meltwater Champions Chess Tour I guess)* : AFAIK, Norway is where Jovanka has been living for many years, so she doesn't need a special reason to be there...